# Better way to avoid joining the same table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table Animal with the structure given below

```
AnimalId    Feature Present
--------    ------- -------
1           Teeth   Yes
1           Leg     Yes
2           Teeth   No
2           Leg     Yes 
3           Teeth   Yes
3           Leg     Yes
```

I would need to retrieve the animalid if both teeth and lege are 'Yes'
I have written a query like

---

```
select distinct A1.AnimalId from Animal A1
inner join Animal A2 on
A1.AnimalId = 
(select distinct A2.AnimalId from Animal A2 
 inner join Animal A3 on
 A2.AnimalId = 
(select distinct A3.AnimalId from Animal A3 where A3.Feature = 'Leg' and A3.Present = 'Yes'  group by A3.AnimalId)
where A2.Feature = 'Teeth' and A2.Present = 'Yes'  group by A2.AnimalId)
```

---

and its working.

would like to know is there any better way to write this and achieve the same result.

Comment: Why are you joining at all?  Just query the table and use a "where" clause...

Comment: Beware the dreaded EAV ([Entity Attribute Value Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)); it generally makes querying hard, as you've just found out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to approach this type of query using `group by` and `having`.  In your case:

```
select a.animalId
from animal a
where (a.feature = 'Teeth' and a.present = 'Yes') or
      (a.feature = 'Leg' and a.present = 'Yes')
group by a.animalId
having count(distinct a.feature) = 2;
```

The `where` clause can be simplified to:

```
where a.feature in ('Teeth', 'Leg') and a.present = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the query .. its  perfectly working.. i have a few more feature like nose and ear and the condition is both leg and teeth should be  present but either nose or ear could be there .. so i changed the query to  "select a.animalId
from animal a
 where (a.feature in ('Teeth', 'Leg','','','','','','') and a.present = 'Yes') 
 and (
           (a.feature = 'Nose' and a.Present = 'No') 
        or (a.feature = 'Ear'  and a.Present = 'No') 
    ) 
group by a.animalId
having count(distinct a.feature) = 4;". but its not working any idea y?

Comment: Thanks.. Its working .. Modified it to                                                               select a.animalId
from animal a
 where (a.feature in ('Teeth', 'Leg','','','','','','') and a.present = 'Yes') 
or (a.feature = 'Nose' and a.Present = 'No'  or (a.feature = 'Nose' and a.Present = 'Yes')) 
 or (a.feature = 'Ear'  and a.Present = 'No' or (a.feature = 'Nose' and a.Present = 'Yes'))    
group by a.animalId
having count(distinct a.feature) = 4;

Comment: Keep in mind there are two aspects to this: the maintainability (or syntactic preference) of the actual query and the performance of the query. One form may look better to you but perform worse or vice versa. Another option would use `EXISTS` and this may perform better or worse, and it may be more or less maintainable. Don't think because you are writing it differently that the query does any more or less work - only the query plan tells you that.